# Какой движок использует класс CDBTree?

Tags: php

Возникла задача поднять сайт. Доступ по FTP есть, однако для настройки nginx необходимо понять какой CMS или Framework используется.
Автоматическое распознавание движка сайта через itrack.ru не дало результатов. 
Вот код index.php

```
<?php

include('include/head.php');

$TITLE = c_utils::$config['site_name_full'];
$KEYWORDS = c_utils::$config['keywords'];
$METADESC = c_utils::$config['metadesc'];

//--------- Новости ---------

require(PATH_CLASS.'news.php');
$ntree = new CDBTree($utils, $utils->DBT['nstruct'], $utils->DBT['ncat'], 'idcat', array('left' => 'cleft', 'right' => 'cright', 'level' => 'clevel'));
$nstruct = new c_struct($ntree, $utils->DBT['nstruct'], $utils->DBT['ncat']);
$nstruct->sql_connect();

$news = new c_news($utils->DBT['news'], $utils->DBT['ncat'], $utils->DBT['news_media'], $utils->DBT['media'], 'idnews');
$news->sql_connect();

$res_news = $news->news_list( 1, 1, 0, 1, '', date('d.m.Y', c_utils::now()), '', c_utils::$config['npp_main'] );

//---------------------------


include(PATH_TEMPLATES.'index.php');

?>
```

А это структура папок внутри www

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вы не думали что это возможно обычная самопись?

Comment: С близкой к единице вероятностью это не движок

Comment: многие Framework используют MVC а тут нет такой структуры так что скорее всего этого не Framework. Скорее всего самопис.

Comment: Как в таком случае настроить nginx?

Comment: @NikolayKorotkov а в чём конкретно проблема? Вроде бы все PHP-сайты настраиваются одинаково независимо от движка

Comment: @NikolayKorotkov сайт раньше на Apache работал? Смотрите правила в .htaccess. Можете нам содержимое файла этого показать?

Comment: @NikolayKorotkov сайт сейчас по какому-нибудь адресу работает? Что вы в itrack.ru вводили?

Answer (score 0):

Это похоже Magento.

Смотрите, например, [описание класса CDBTree](http://freegento.com/doc/d2/db5/class_c_d_b_tree.html).